# List adapter with different value than what's shown as text

Tags: android, android-activity, android-adapter

I've started learning android programming and I'm stuck, I'm not sure how to work with the listadapter,(the app should be a personal trainer, you get 3 activities where you choose like type of training, home or gym and intensity, based on what you choose it should show you the exercises) I've set a list and upon clicking on one of the two choices, the path to the next activity is created with an intent as seen in the code, however, the activity name is different than what is shown as text in the list. I feel my logic is failing here but can't find a way to do this other than if elses.
(and maybe it would be easier to just do this with buttons or anyway views of some sort and onclicklisteners)

2nd thing, can I move the position of the list and the text inside the list (to the middle for example) if it is programmed this way in java? Like in xml with padding or something? Thanks

```
public class WorkoutPlace extends ListActivity {

String classes[] = { "WORKOUTHOME" , "WORKOUTGYM" };
// these should be   "HOME Workout", "GYM Workout"

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(WorkoutPlace.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String Home_Gym = classes[position];
    try{
    Class ourClass = Class.forName("totaltrainer.com." + Home_Gym);
    Intent ourIntent = new Intent(WorkoutPlace.this, ourClass);
    startActivity(ourIntent);
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I really doubt you get another class than the one you click in the list. What happens when you click the first item?

Comment: I think I didn't explain myself well, I get the class I want, however, I want the user to see "HOME Workout" & "GYM Workout" in the options list instead of "WORKOUTHOME" & "WORKOUTGYM" which in the code is the path to those activities.

Comment: Look at implementing a custom adapter or at adapting your data.

Answer (score 0):

Define a parallel array that contain the actual classes, like this:

```
String classes[] = { "HOME Workout" , "GYM Workout" };
Class actualClasses[] = { totaltrainer.com.WORKOUTHOME.class,
                          totaltrainer.com.WORKOUTGYM.class };
```

In `onListItemClick()` do:

```
Intent ourIntent = new Intent(WorkoutPlace.this, actualClasses[position]);
startActivity(ourIntent);
```

**Note:** You really should change the names of your classes so they aren't all UPPERCASE. Use `WorkoutGym` instead of `WORKOUTGYM`.